# How to fix the image while scrolling using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to fix the image while the side content will scroll and until the footer.

```html
<header>
  <p>Menu</p>
</header>
<div class="col-md-8">
  <p>Some Content</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Any help is  much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Did one of the answers below solve your problem? If so, please accept one of them using the green check mark. It lets the answerers know that your problem has been solved. If not, please expand on what problems you are continuing to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position: sticky`.
Then it will be `relative` until page is scrolled, where it will become `fixed`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: white;
}

main, aside, header, footer {
  padding: 10px;
}

header, footer {
  background: #693;
}

#content {
  display: flex;
  height: 150vh;
  width: 100%;
}

main {
  background: #349;
  height: 150vh;
  flex-grow: 4;
}

aside {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 50vh;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  HEADER
</header>
<div id="content">
  <main>
      MAIN
  </main>
  <aside>
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8?s=80&d=identicon">
  </aside>
</div>
<footer>
  FOOTER
</footer>
```

Comment: You can thank by marking it as correct ;)

Answer (score 2):

To position an element to fix while scolling, there is a simple property available in css `position:fixed`

for example

```
 img { position: fixed; }
```